# Extract phone number of whatsapp message by means of Twilio integration a Dialogflow

Tags: twilio, dialogflow-es, whatsapp

I have a chatbot in Dialogflow integrated with Twilio that can be accessed through WhatsApp.
I need extract the number of the user who communicates with the bot, to search the database if it is registered.

Comment: How have you connected WhatsApp to Dialogflow through Twilio? Can you talk through that integration?